# How to convert from PhotoResult or BitmapImage to Bitmap?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, bitmapimage, nokia-imaging-sdk, lumia-imaging-sdk

How to convert from PhotoResult to Bitmap in Nokia Imaging SDK?
I wish to break an image into smaller images. 
The Bitmap class in `Nokia.Graphics.Imaging` has a constructor which takes another bitmap and a rectangle. I wish to use it.
I cannot find any good examples on this. Please assist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah - you can first create an EditingSession with

```
var session = await EditingSessionFactory.CreateEditingSessionAsync(photoResult.ChosenPhoto);
```

([documentation here](http://developer.nokia.com/Resources/Library/Imaging_API_Ref/#!nokiagraphicsimaging-namespace/editingsessionfactory-class/editingsessionfactory-methods/createeditingsessionasync-method/createeditingsessionasync-method-stream.html))
and then render that to a Bitmap with [RenderToBitmapAsync()](http://developer.nokia.com/Resources/Library/Imaging_API_Ref/#!nokiagraphicsimaging-namespace/editingsession-class/editingsession-methods/rendertobitmapasync-method/rendertobitmapasync-method-bitmap-outputoption-rect.html) (which has an overload that takes a Rect)

Hope that helps!

old answer:

I'm not sure what a PhotoResult is, but [here's the documentation for the constructor you mentioned](http://developer.nokia.com/Resources/Library/Imaging_API_Ref/#!nokiagraphicsimaging-namespace/bitmap-class/bitmap-constructor/bitmap-constructor-bitmap-rect.html). What question do you have about it?

Comment: PhotoResult is the class of the object returned when using a PhotoChooser task in Windows Phone. The documentation provided there is inadequate for this scenario.

Answer (score 2):

In the new version 1.0 of the Nokia Imaging SDK, you can use StreamImageSource to read the ChosenPhoto stream.

Answer (score 0):

NokiaImagingSDK 1.2

```
Bitmap bmp = null;
await streamImageSource.GetBitmapAsync(bmp, OutputOption.PreserveAspectRatio);
```